# accessing camera and mic in sandboxed iframe from different subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, twilio, twilio-video

I have basic video chat nodeJS webapp using twilio javascript SDK

video.xyz.com

which I am trying to add in a iframe of a webapplet running on different webservice and sub domain

demo.xyz.com

Browser shows Camera and microphone access prompt when i run directly and it works fine. But inside iframe i am not able to access camera and mic.

Both webapplets are running on same port but different subdomains.

I have tried setting `document.domain` on video chat app to match parent page app where iframe will be added, but didn't get that to work.
I get this error in chrome:

`"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': Assignment is forbidden for sandboxed iframes."`

I do have allow mic and camera attribute.

```
<iframe allow="camera; microphone" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" src="https://video.xyz.com"></iframe>
```

What do i need to do get camera access in iframe? Which web app will need this change? Does this need CORS?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you request the camera/microphone from the iframe instead?

Comment: Brad, I tried that using allow attributes. <iframe src="https://video.xyz.com" allow="microphone; camera"></iframe>
Do you mean some other way?

Comment: Yeah, I meant instead of making the request from the outer frame, request your camera/microphone from the code ran within the iframe.

Comment: ok, how can i do that?  as it works standalone so not understanding what i need to do different when i run it in iframe.

Comment: @user5775613 did you solve it ?

Comment: @TSR were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Any update on how this was resolved? I'm currently having the same issue on chrome 81

Comment: I believe you also need to set `sandbox="allow-same-origin"`.

Answer (score 24):

Just read https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bigbluebutton-dev/jauJm_sBbU8

This worked before:

```
<iframe src="example.com" allow="camera; microphone"/>
```

In my case , the webpage has a HTTP response header: 
"Content-Security-Policy: child-src 'self' *;"
And the URL's origin in Iframe is not the same as its parent's URL origin.

But now we should do like this:(tested in Chrome Version 83.0.4103.61 )

```
<iframe src="example.com" allow="camera https://example.com; microphone https://example.com"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Piece of cake:

```
<iframe
       title="Open identification process"
       src="xxx.com"
       frameBorder="0"
       width="600"
       height="800"
       allow="camera; microphone"
     />
```