# iframe allow attribute after pageload

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to set "allow" attribute on iframe either on page load or "on-click" event.

Below is my sample HTML code:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<br/>
<iframe id="allow_test" src="https://www.example.com/someDeviceTest.html" width="300" height="300" />
```

Note that in the above iframe tag, `allow` attribute is not there to start with.

Script:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("button clicked");
    document.getElementById("allow_test").setAttribute("allow", "microphone;");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
        console.log("Onload set attribute");
        document.getElementById("allow_test").setAttribute("allow", "microphone;");
}, false);
```

I can see the allow attribute being added into the iframe with both tests when I inspect. But the microphone access is still denied.
Allow attribute is not being honored if I set it via `setAttribute`.

After page load, just reloading iframe alone makes it work (i.e. successfully gets access to microphone successfully)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing camera and mic in sandboxed iframe from different subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008648/accessing-camera-and-mic-in-sandboxed-iframe-from-different-subdomain)

Comment: @Hugo, Nope it does not. Sandbox adds more restrictions.
Another point in above question link, it already has `allow="camera; microphone"`. I want to add this attribute dynamically after the page load.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `allow` attribute before src and setting the value from javascript worked.

Comment: Could you please give an example?